# What's the relationship between $O(\log(x+y))$ and $O(\log(xy))$

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

Which of these bounds, $O(\log(x+y))$ and $O(\log(xy))$, is tighter? Or are they equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sufficiently large $x,y$:

$$x+y \leq xy \leq \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)^2$$

and so

$$ \log(x+y) \leq \log(xy) \leq 2 \log(x+y) - \log(4) $$